# Observable+Hikari fetching data time is different in different environments

Tags: spring-boot, java-8, observable, hikaricp

I am using JDBC Observable+Hikari to fetch data from database, when i connect to UAT env, fetching data is within mins but when I point it to PROD, the process gets stuck at blockingSubscribe() and it takes time in hrs to complete it, we tried changing version of spring boot  and hikari as well. The PROD server is in same datacenter.Many other Java applications are using the same approach but not facing this, it returns approx 6K record for one batch

We are using two different oracle database in code which are on different version, can this be  the reason?

Can anyone help me in understanding this?,

Can this be a network related issue?

We are using IN clause in our query, in two batches each of 999 IN clause elements.. can this be issue?We also tried to change the in clause to 50 elements still the same issue?

I am using JDBC Observable+Hikari on jdk8 to fetch data from database, when i connect to UAT env, fetching data is within mins but when I point it to PROD, the process gets stuck at blockingSubscribe() and it takes time in hrs to complete it, we tried changing version of spring boot  and hikari as well. The PROD server is in same datacenter.Many other Java applications are using the same approach but not facing this, it returns approx 6K record for one batch

We are using two different oracle database in code which are on different version, can this be  the reason?

Can anyone help me in understanding this?,

Can this be a network related issue?

We are using IN clause in our query, in two batches each of 999 IN clause elements.. can this be issue?We also tried to change the in clause to 50 elements still the same issue?

Can it happen that when code hits blockingSubscribe(), the call is not immediately hitting the backend database?